# how to teleport assets between statemint and polkadot in javascript

Tags: polkadot-js, statemint, teleport, westend

i have not found the examples to teleport between statemint and polkadot. is ther any one can give some examples in javascript.what i use is

```
@polkadot/api
```

this is my code:

i have found the teleport function.but there is some error

```
async function teleport() {
    let api = await getConn();
    
    let fromAddr = ADDR_1;
    let mnemonic = MNEMONIC_1;
    let toAddr=ADDR_2;
    let amount = new BigNumber(5).multipliedBy(westendDecimal).toString(10);
    let tx = api.tx.polkadotXcm.limitedTeleportAssets(toAddr,toAddr,amount,0,100000);
    await sendTransaction(mnemonic,fromAddr,tx);
}
```

but it execute error:

```
xecute error: Error: createType(Call):: Call: failed decoding polkadotXcm.limitedTeleportAssets:: Struct: failed on args: {"dest":"{\"_enum\":{\"V0\":\"XcmV0MultiLocation\",\"V1\":\"XcmV1MultiLocation\"}}","beneficiary":"{\"_enum\":{\"V0\":\"XcmV0MultiLocation\",\"V1\":\"XcmV1MultiLocation\"}}","assets":"{\"_enum\":{\"V0\":\"Vec<XcmV0MultiAsset>\",\"V1\":\"XcmV1MultiassetMultiAssets\"}}","fee_asset_item":"u32","weight_limit":"{\"_enum\":{\"Unlimited\":\"Null\",\"Limited\":\"Compact<u64>\"}}"}:: Struct: failed on dest: {"_enum":{"V0":"XcmV0MultiLocation","V1":"XcmV1MultiLocation"}}:: Cannot map Enum JSON, unable to find '5EWFCfvUqSkUVbsPSJNAkfGVqVTVwfc1c5XAg3qomDUR5eiR' in v0, v1
```

Answer (score 1):

well~.i have found the result finaly.any one has the question can see https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/blob/master/packages/page-parachains/src/Teleport.tsx#L77-L126

my test code is as follows:
https://github.com/polariseye/polka_statemint_test